# CEF CefRenderProcessHandler::OnContextCreated not called

Tags: chromium-embedded

Who tried add native function to javascript in CEF? It was not work, simple to reappear:

1. download the CEF3 binary package (1750)
2. open cefclient2010.sln
3. open client_app.cpp which in cefclient project
4. goto line 110, set a breakpoint
5. F5
6. input any url, any try, the breakpoint never breaked

Am I missed some steps? or some settings?

Comment: I know the reason, http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=5267  but another problem is: step by https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/wiki/JavaScriptIntegration, the registered function not called...

Answer (score 5):

i had the same problem
you must add **CefRenderProcessHandler** interface in SimpleApp ，then the most important is you must implement `CefApp::GetRenderProcessHandler() method`.
just like this：

```
virtual CefRefPtr<CefRenderProcessHandler> GetRenderProcessHandler() {
      return this;
  }
```

by default, the **base class return NULL**，so `OnContextCreated()` will not call.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it has something to do with the process model? How can you tell if the function is getting called? If by using a debugger, make sure you attached all child-processes too.

Answer (score 1):

By default sample CEF application is multi-process. Either attach CEF render process to the debugger or simply do following (force the CEF app run into single process mode):

```
  CefSettings settings;

#ifdef _DEBUG
  settings.single_process = true;
#endif
```