# OnContextCreated() in Cef not being called

Tags: javascript, event-handling, chromium-embedded

I have a similar problem to the person in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22471582/cef-cefrenderprocesshandleroncontextcreated-not-called); I'm trying to extend the cefsimple.exe app included with the chromium embedded framework binaries to include a V8 handler. I implemented the `OnContextCreated()` method and made sure to extend `RenderProcessHandler` in the `SimpleHandler` class. I'm trying to implement a simple window bound variable called `test_string`; here's what my code looks like;

```
void SimpleHandler::OnContextCreated(
    CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
    CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
    CefRefPtr<CefV8Context> context)
{
    CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> object = context->GetGlobal();

    object->SetValue("test_string", CefV8Value::CreateString("this is a test"), V8_PROPERTY_ATTRIBUTE_NONE);
}
```

But the program never arrives at any breakpoints I add within the method, and the variable is undefined on any webpages I load within the app. I saw that one of the solutions in the other thread is to enable the `settings.single_process` flag, which i've done, but my code still doesn't reach the breakpoint.

To be clear, I'm accessing the variable on pages with `window.test_string`.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are sending that **CefApp** to **CefExecuteProcess**.

```
  CefRefPtr<SimpleApp> app(new SimpleApp);

  // CEF applications have multiple sub-processes (render, plugin, GPU, etc)
  // that share the same executable. This function checks the command-line and,
  // if this is a sub-process, executes the appropriate logic.
  int exit_code = CefExecuteProcess(main_args, app, sandbox_info);
  if (exit_code >= 0) {
    // The sub-process has completed so return here.
    return exit_code;
  }
```

Found this solution [here](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=11072#p18647)

Answer (score 0):

Have you read through the `General Usage` guide? Some key points below

https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/GeneralUsage#markdown-header-cefapp
https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/GeneralUsage#markdown-header-processes

The `single_process` mode is not supported so I've never used it. In general I'd avoid it. The multi process architecture means you need to attach the debugger to the process. The `Chromium` guide is relevant to `CEF` in this instance.

https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/debugging-on-windows#TOC-Attaching-to-the-renderer

Comment: I'll look into this, but as of right now I'm unable to debug my code due to a separate problem. I'll get back to you if this is applicable.

Comment: I've read through the page headers you linked to, and I'm having a great difficulty understanding what needs to be done. I tried adding `CEF_REQUIRE_RENDERER_THREAD();` to the top of my function implementation, but it still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Do you have a specific question or some code to reference?

Answer (score 0):

you need to ensure your App is derived from CefRenderProcessHandler 
not SimpleHandler!!!

```
class SimpleApp : public CefApp
    , public CefRenderProcessHandler 
{

virtual void OnContextCreated(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
    CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
    CefRefPtr<CefV8Context> context) OVERRIDE;
```

valdemar-rudolfovich says you need to pass instance of SimpleApp in 
CefExecuteProcess